# find pano id from location in google street view api

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

How do you look up the pano id for the pano field (from a location) in the google street view api? Basically, instead of just loading a regular image, how do you have the api return the image of a cylindrical or spherical panorama?

Answer (score 2):

The new [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) API will let you query for the availability of Street View panoramas at given locations (by address or latlng). If a panorama is found, the response will include its pano IDs. These queries are free of charge.